# Cell reference to a powerquery

Tags: vba, excel, powerquery

I have a Power Query in which I'm trying to get the link in a cell `Z13` from "Shift Sched" sheet. The link in `Z13` will get me the excel file in which I have the data. Cell name is defined as `REFCELL`

Here is a wat i got from record macro.
Sub powerquery()
'
' powerquery Macro
'

'
    Range("W13").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Schedules", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents(""https://portal.ant.website.com/sites/wfl/Shift Schedules/Shift Schedules and Emp Details w.e.f Jun 03, 2018-HYD.xlsx""), null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Schedules_Sheet = Source{[Item=""Schedules"",Kind=""Sheet""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Schedules_Sheet,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type" & _
        " text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type any}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", type text}, {""Column7"", type any}, {""Column8"", type any}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}, {""Column11"", type text}, {""Column12"", type text}, {""Column13"", type text}, {""Column14"", type text}, {""Column15"", type text}, {""Column16"", type" & _
        " text}, {""Column17"", type text}, {""Column18"", type text}, {""Column19"", type any}, {""Column20"", type text}, {""Column21"", type text}, {""Column22"", type text}, {""Column23"", type any}, {""Column24"", type any}, {""Column25"", type any}, {""Column26"", type any}, {""Column27"", type any}, {""Column28"", type any}, {""Column29"", type any}, {""Column30"", ty" & _
        "pe any}, {""Column31"", type text}, {""Column32"", type any}, {""Column33"", type text}, {""Column34"", type text}, {""Column35"", type text}, {""Column36"", type any}, {""Column37"", type text}, {""Column38"", type text}, {""Column39"", type any}, {""Column40"", type any}, {""Column41"", type any}, {""Column42"", type text}, {""Column43"", type any}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""C" & _
        "hanged Type"""
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Schedules;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Schedules]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = False
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Schedules_2"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End Sub

**This is not working for me because the link keeps changing depending on the date ex. Jun 03, 2018. The link has to be taken from the cell z13 in "Shift Sched" Sheet and load in a new sheet.

Comment: So does Z13 contain a file path for a file you want to load? And what does not working mean? Is there an error? What is it?

Comment: yes, it has the path to a excel sheet (https://portal.ant.website.com/sites/wfl/Shift Schedules/Shift Schedules and Emp Details w.e.f Jun 03, 2018-HYD.xlsx) This keeps changing with date.
I want a VBA code where it should get this file downloaded to a new sheet by taking the web link in z13.


)

Answer (score 0):

It's nearly all related to getting your `""` quotation marks in the right place to asemble your query string correctly. Try this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add _
    Name:="Schedules", _
    Formula:="let" & vbCr & _
            vbTab & "MyURL = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=""REFCELL""]}[Content][Column1]{0}," & vbCr & _
            vbTab & "Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(MyURL))" & vbCr & _
            "in Source"
```

Comment: I got the below query and got an error.
**************
Expression.Error: The key didn't match any rows in the table.
Details:
    Key=Record
    Table=Table
***************************************************
*****************************************************
let
 MyURL = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="REFCELL"]}[Content][Column1]{0},
 Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(MyURL)),
Schedules_Sheet = Source{[Item="Schedules",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Schedules_Sheet,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text},
in
    #"Changed Type"

Comment: What's the URL you're trying to query?